# Added Scrapy rules but not scraped more item

Tags: python, scrapy

In my Scrapy output file, I found that some items are missing, so I manually add those missing page as the third rule.

```
class KjvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'kjv'
    start_urls = ['file:///G:/OEBPS2/bible-toc.xhtml']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'OEBPS'), follow=True),      # 1st rule

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\d\.xhtml$'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=False),             # 2nd rule
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'2-jn.xhtml$', r'jude.xhtml$', r'obad.xhtml$', r'philem.xhtml$'], ),
             callback='parse_item', follow=False),             # 3rd rule
    )
```

If I enable `1st rule` and `3rd rule` (comment out the `2nd rule`), I can download the four missing items correctly but not the whole items(about 2000 itmes).

But if I enable all three rules, it turns out that the missing items still missing. (i.e. There is not difference if I add the `3rd rule`.)

I don't know why the rules doesn't work.

Any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that I must deny these missing urls in the `1st rule`, so that in the `3rd rule`, it will not be filtered out as duplicated requests.
So it will be fetch normally.

e.g.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'OEBPS',deny=(r'2-jn.xhtml$', r'jude.xhtml$', 
         r'obad.xhtml$',r'philem.xhtml$')), follow=True),   # 1st rule

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\d\.xhtml$'),
         callback='parse_item', follow=False),              # 2nd rule
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'2-jn.xhtml$', r'jude.xhtml$', r'obad.xhtml$', r'philem.xhtml$'], ),
         callback='parse_item', follow=False),              # 3rd rule
)
```